# Why do we use an inner class Node inside class LinkedList for Linked List implementation on Java?

Tags: java, linked-list, inner-classes, singly-linked-list

```
class LinkedList
{
    Node head;  // head of list

    /* Linked list Node*/
    class Node
    {
        int data;
        Node next;

        // Constructor to create a new node
        // Next is by default initialized
        // as null
        Node(int d) {data = d;}
    }
}
```

What is the need for nested class?Is there any **alternative** for it?

Comment: There are always alternatives. Your question is very unclear.

Comment: it is for hiding of the implementation - you do not necessarily know about types the class operates with internally.

Comment: @NathanHughes 'Static inner' is a contradiction in terms.

Comment: If you're asking about some code please make sure you post where you got it from (each JDK implementor (oracle, ibm, openjdk) may have its own implementation) and make sure the code posted accurately reflects that code